# Why does one software slow down when receiving data from another via UDP (python)?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, cinema-4d

I'm constantly sending a camera's position matrix via UDP from Houdini and setting it in Cinema4d. Both are 3-D software programs. The data sends fine but Cinema4d freezes and is slow when updating the matrix from houdini. Why is this happening?

**here is the python code i'm sending from Houdini:**

```
import socket

UDP_IP = '192.168.1.8'
UDP_PORT = 7864

cam = hou.selectedNodes()
camerac4d =  hou.node('/obj/obj_andcamera/cam1')
xform = camerac4d.worldTransform() #get the camera matrix
data_string = str(xform)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(data_string, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

**UDP receiver in Cinema 4d:**

```
import socket

def main():
    operateon = doc.SearchObject('Camera') #get cinema 4d camera

    UDP_IP = '192.168.1.8'
    UDP_PORT = 7864

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
    data_string,addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)


    data_string = ast.literal_eval(data_string) #converts string list


    #set houdini matrix to cinema 4d camera

    off = v(newlist[3][0],newlist[3][1], -newlist[3][2]) 
    v1 = v(-newlist[0][0],newlist[0][1], newlist[0][2])
    v2 = v(-newlist[1][0], -newlist[1][1], -newlist[1][2])
    v3 = v(-newlist[2][0], -newlist[2][1], newlist[2][2])

    mat = c4d.Matrix(off,v1*-1,v2*-1,v3)

    newpos = operateon.SetMg(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

so i figured it out i just had to stick the matrix setting in a while loop that died after 5 tries so that cinema4d wouldn't crash and then had to update the viewport in cinema with a line of code that refreshes the viewport everytime the matrix gets updated at the end

def main():

```
operateon = doc.SearchObject('Camera') #find and set the cinema camera

##UDP receive transformation matrix from houdini##

UDP_IP = 'localhost'
UDP_PORT = 7864

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
##kill the connection after 5 viewport updates/works but stupid/but it stops cinema from freezing on an endless while loop
die = 0
while die < 5:
    die += 1
    data_string, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

# set each vector component 
    data_string = ast.literal_eval(data_string) #converts string to list 

    #a hou matrix is 4x4, cinema is a 3x4 matrix consisting of :off=position data, v1,v2,v3 stores the scale,rotation and shear
    index = 3  #Delete column 3 
    newlist = [ (x[0:index] + x[index+1:])  for x in data_string]
#print newlist
#---------------------set vectors for matrix---------------------------------#
    off = v(newlist[3][0],newlist[3][1], -newlist[3][2]) 
    v1 = v(-newlist[0][0],newlist[0][1], newlist[0][2])
    v2 = v(-newlist[1][0], -newlist[1][1], -newlist[1][2])
    v3 = v(-newlist[2][0], -newlist[2][1], newlist[2][2])

#---------------------create a matrix and set it---------------------------------#

    mat = c4d.Matrix(off,v1*-1,v2*-1,v3)
    newpos = operateon.SetMg(mat)


    #update the viewport with the new matrix 
    c4d.EventAdd()
    c4d.DrawViews(c4d.DRAWFLAGS_ONLY_ACTIVE_VIEW|c4d.DRAWFLAGS_NO_THREAD|c4d.DRAWFLAGS_NO_REDUCTION|c4d.DRAWFLAGS_STATICBREAK)
```